# Constructivity of two problems on a standard simplex?

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory, proof-theory, constructive-mathematics, integer-programming

Maximizing a hyperplane $\sum_i a_ix_i$ where $a_i\in\mathbb R$ and each $a_i$ are fixed and non-negative and $x_i$ are variables over a standard simplex $\sum_i x_i\leq 1$ with $0\leq x_i$ always produces a vertex point on the simplex and maximization corresponds to $\max_i a_i$.

> 1. In infinite dimensions is such a proof considered constructive or does it hold only in classical logic? It seems that we would have to show that at maximizing point there is an $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_i=1$ holds and for that perhaps is it possible we cannot do this without invoking [LLPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_principle_of_omniscience)?

Suppose we are looking for a $0/1$ vector in integers (not reals as in 1.) on the standard simplex and we know the optimal vector has either sum of even coordinates summing to $1$ or odd coordinates summing to $1$ then in finite dimensions it is a process of enumerating vertices.

> 2. In infinite dimensions is such a proof considered constructive or does it hold only in classical logic? It seems that we would have to show that at optimizing point there is an $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $x_i=1$ holds and for that perhaps is it possible we cannot do this without invoking [LLPO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_principle_of_omniscience)?

In general is the proofs of optimization over infinite dimensions considered constructive?

3a. How about when each $a_i$ are fixed and positive?

3b. How about when each $a_i$ are fixed and distinct and non-negative thus guaranteeing an unique vertex point?

3c. How about when each $a_i$ are fixed and distinct and positive thus guaranteeing an unique vertex point?

Comment: How do you show that the claim in the first sentence of your question holds constructively in finitely many dimensions?

Comment: You need to say that the $a_i$ are *positive*. Them being non-negative is not good enough. Also, you're going to destroy the question and my answer if you edit the question this way. It's better to ask another question, I think, or add an extra question at the end.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Added 3a, 3b and 3c.

Comment: 3a changes nothing. For 3b and 3c a good rule of thumb is that unique solutions can generally be computed constructively, unless they're unstable (they move a lot when the parameters are perturbed slightly).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Even in infinite dimensions? Looks like we have to show there is a $1$ in even or odd coordinates which is LLPO.

Comment: Well, for infinite dimensions you're just asking for something like finding the index at which an infnite seqence attains its maximum, and that's not going to be computable in general. In any case, the method from my answer can be extended, I am pretty sure.

Comment: @AndrejBauer So you think it will not be constructive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make an erroneous assumption in your question, as already in dimension 1 you need LLPO to know that the maximum is actually attained at some point.

We work constructively.

**Theorem:** *LLPO is equivalent to the statement that every affine map $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ attains its maximum*

*Proof.* The general form of an affine map on $[0,1]$ is $f_{a,b}(x) = a \cdot (1 - x) + b \cdot x$. Suppose then that for every such $f_{a,b}$ there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f_{a,b}(x) \leq f_{a,b}(x_0)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Let us first show that LLPO implies attainment of maximum. Given any $f_{a,b}$, by LLPO either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$:

- If $a \leq b$ then the maximum of $f_{a,b}$ is attained at $x_0 = 1$.
- If $b \leq a$ then the maximum of $f_{a,b}$ is attained at $x_0 = 0$.

The converse is more interesting. First note that the following holds: if $f_{a,b}(0) \leq f_{a,b}(t)$ for some $t > 0$ then $f_{a,b}(0) \leq f_{a,b}(1)$. Similarly, if $f_{a,b}(t) \geq f_{a,b}(1)$ for some $t < 1$ then $f_{a,b}(0) \geq f_{a,b}(1)$.

Consider any two reals $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. We shall decide $a \leq b \lor b \leq a$, which implies LLPO. By assumption, the map $f_{a,b}$ attains its maximum at some $x_0 \in [0,1]$. Either $x_0 < 2/3$ or $x_0 > 1/3$:

- If $x_0 > 1/3$ then from $f(0) \leq f(x_0)$ it follows that $a = f(0) \leq f(1) = b$.
- If $x_0 < 2/3$ then from $f(x_0) \geq f(1)$ it follows that $a = f(0) \geq f(1) = b$. $\Box$

Of course, since affine maps are very simple, the maximal *value* of $f_{a,b}$ exists, but the above argument shows it takes LLPO to know *where* it is attained.

Comment: So there is no constructive proof?

Comment: That's what the theorem says. I improved it to show your claim in dimension 1 is equivalent to LLPO.

Comment: How about for 2. same? 2. seems to be a discrete problem inherently? Still same? Perhaps for 2. constructive works for finite dimension. Only for infinite dimensions LLPO is needed?

Comment: For 2. we are in $\{0,1\}$ vectors not $[0,1]$ and thus I think discrete.

Comment: No, you still get LLPO. You have $f(0) = a$ and $f(1) = b$. If you can pick $x_0 \in \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x_0)$ is maximal, then you can decide whether $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$: if $x_0 = 0$ then $a = f(0) \geq f(1) = b$, and if $x_0 = 1$ then $b = f(1) \geq f(0) = a$.

Comment: Interesting. So no useful optimization problem is in constructive logic?

Comment: Quite on the contrary. Constructive logic is telling you that it is *numerically unstable* to try to compute the point at which the maximum is attained. This is a fact of life that numerical analysts know very well. But under extra conditions you can do it constructively, for example, if you know that the function is non-constant in every dimension. You can also show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ you can find $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)$ is within $\epsilon$-error of true maximum.

Comment: Affine functions $\sum_i a_ix_i$ are non constant at every dimension which was what the problem was about.

Comment: The $a_i$ could all be zero, or just some of them.

Comment: Ok clarified on $a_i$.